# Vb When setting price to display in a text box it doesn't display the correct value

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, textbox

I am making a pizza ordering system and I have set the value of price to 0 so that I can add other values onto it later. So when I try to have it display the price as the user selects their items in a text box for some reason is isn't displaying the correct price

```
Public Class Form1
    Public price As Double
    Public Psmall As Double = 4.0
    Public Pmedium As Double = 7.0
    Public Plarge As Double = 9.0
    Public Pcrusts As Double = 2.0
    Public Pside As Double = 2.5
    Public Pdesert As Double = 2.5
    Public Pdrinks As Double = 1.0
    Public Pizzas As Double = 4.0



    Private Sub Psize_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Psize.SelectedIndexChanged

        For Each Item As Object In Psize.SelectedItem
            orders.AppendText(Item.ToString)
            If Psize.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
                price += 4
            ElseIf Psize.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
                price += 7 * 1
            ElseIf Psize.SelectedIndex = 2 Then
                price += 9 * 1

            End If

            TextBox1.Text = String.Format("{0:C}", price)

        Next

    End Sub

    Private Sub Pcrust_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Pcrust.SelectedIndexChanged
        For Each Item As Object In Pcrust.SelectedItem
            orders.AppendText(Item.ToString)
            price += Pcrusts


        Next

    End Sub

    Private Sub Pizza_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Pizza.SelectedIndexChanged
        For Each Item As Object In Pizza.SelectedItem
            orders.AppendText(Item.ToString)
            price += Pizzas
        Next

    End Sub

    Private Sub Oside_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Oside.SelectedIndexChanged
        For Each Item As Object In Oside.SelectedItem
            orders.AppendText(Item.ToString)
            price += Pside
        Next

    End Sub

    Private Sub Odesert_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Odesert.SelectedIndexChanged
        For Each Item As Object In Odesert.SelectedItem
            orders.AppendText(Item.ToString)
            price += Pdesert
        Next

    End Sub

    Private Sub Pdrink_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Pdrink.SelectedIndexChanged
        For Each Item As Object In Pdrink.SelectedItem
            orders.AppendText(Item.ToString)
            price += Pdrinks
        Next


    End Sub

    Private Sub orders_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles orders.TextChanged

    End Sub


    Private Sub tcost_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

    End Sub
End Class
```

Above is the code, I have tried using just raw numbers instead of the variable I had already declared and neither has worked

Here is a link to how the code is displaying the price in the form when executed 
http://prntscr.com/abmj0a

Comment: This is not vba.  vba<>vb.net.  It is close but many rules and syntax will not cross over between the two.  I removed the vba tag.

Answer (score 0):

i think the **problem is that you increase the price every time the user select something in the combobox**.

So if the user first selects a small pizza, but then changes this to medium pizza, you would set:

```
prize+=4 'Now the price is at 4
prize+=7 'Now the price is at 11 (4 before and now +7)
```

So in the end the price would be at 11.

My solution would be:
**Declare a price variable for each combobox**, for example price_size, price_drink, etc..

Now when the user changes the selection of the size Combobox you just say price_size = 4

And when he changes the drink combobox you say price_drink = 1

And in the end you **declare a result_price** = price_size + price_drink + ...

Comment: No that is not the problem, the problem is when i select a small pizza instead of adding 4.0 to the price it is adding 144 thus the price in the box becomes 144

Answer (score 0):

Remove every `For Each` loop in your code. They're **completely** unnecessary and are most likely what's causing your problems.

You are trying to loop through something that technically doesn't exist.

```
For Each Item As Object In Psize.SelectedItem
'SelectedItem is just one single item. There's nothing to loop through!
```

You should also give your `price` variable an initial value to avoid null reference exceptions.

```
Public price As Double = 0.0
```

And lastly, do as julien-100000 said and declare a separate variable holding the price selection for each ComboBox/ListBox.